# iFrame Stop Execution on Timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Weave: http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#e26996be20f992c047117d63848f4a47

I'm building a code playground for mobile devices and while playing with it today I noticed a problem.

The `updatePreview()` function is called whenever a textbox is changed and updates the preview so people can see what their app looks like as they code it.

```
function updatePreview() {
  var previewFrame = document.getElementById("preview")
  var preview =  previewFrame.contentDocument ||  previewFrame.contentWindow.document
  preview.open()
  preview.write("<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset=\"UTF-8\"><title>Document</title><style>" + cssEditor.value + "</style></head><body>"+ htmlEditor.value + "<scr" + "ipt>" + jsEditor.value + "</scr" + "ipt></body></html>")
  preview.close()
}
updatePreview()
```

However when I added the following setInterval function into the javascript section and was making changes. Instead of setInterval calling every second it was constantly being called run at a faster interval adding to the previous interval.

```
var newGradient = function() {
  var randomColor1 = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16),
    randomColor2 = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
    return 'radial-gradient(at top left, ' + randomColor1 + ', ' + randomColor2 + ')';
  };

  setInterval((function() {
    return $('body').css('background', newGradient())
  }), 1000)
```

The problem here is with my `updatePreview()` function.

I've tried `preview.location.reload()`.

I thought maybe by using `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout` to run and stop the function it would solve the problem...

```
var runPreview = setTimeout(function() {
      updatePreview()
    }, 300);
setTimeout(function() {
  updatePreview()
}, 300)

jsEditor.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  clearTimeout(runPreview)
  setTimeout(function() {
    updatePreview()
  }, 300)
})
```

Obviously this isn't working. Does anyone know of a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weave: http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#b6b39c95ec91f42950957a1ac8dc707f

I managed to figure out a (rather crude) way to solve this problem. I append an iframe into a container, and apply the scripts that way. Whenever there's a change the old iframe is removed and the new one is added.

```
document.querySelector(".preview").innerHTML = ""
var frame = document.createElement("iframe")
frame.setAttribute("id", "preview")
frame.setAttribute("sandbox", "allow-forms allow-modals allow-pointer-lock allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts")
document.querySelector(".preview").appendChild(frame)
```